# How to Add item to item display field in dspace?

Tags: dspace

I am unable to get Refrence no  in item display field.

I followed following steps but still when dspace is viewed 
item view it is showing ???.itemlist.dc.refno??? hw can this error be solved.

The following changes were made

1.In Messages.properties

itemlist.dc.refno = **Reference No.**

2.In Dspace.cofig

webui.itemlist.columns = dc.date.issued(date), dc.title,
dc.contributor.*, **dc.refno**

then dspace was rebuilt or fresh installation done. But still i cannot
see Reference No in Browse and item display.

how to fix this error?

Comment: Perhaps this would help: [Fix ???some.key.name??? (JSP)](https://wiki.duraspace.org/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=19006259)

Comment: Are you sure what you're seeing on the page is exactly ???.itemlist.dc.refno??? with the dot after the first set of question markes? In that case, is the last bit in dspace.cfg "dc.refno" or ".dc.refno" with leading dot?

Comment: It is like  ???itemlist.dc.refno???

Comment: The question in the title does not reflect the content of the question.
I don't want to create a question with the same question. I don't think I can, and if I do (because this question was asked 5 years ago), I will be redirected to this topic, because this problem has already been solved here. Although I don't think it was solved.
I request an answer to the question and the detailed procedure, how to Add item to item display field in dspace version 6. Thx